# Move file from a FilesFolder to another FilesFolder of a different Drive

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to move a file from a FilesFolder of DriveId = {X} to another FilesFolder of DriveId = {Y}. I retrieved this Microsoft article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http to achieve my point. In this article you are only able to move a file from a FilesFolder to another FilesFolder when they (both FilesFolders) are both on the same drive.

However it is possible to copy a file between two drives as described in the Microsoft article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http, but this is not the point I want to achieve, because in this case you will have two DriveItemIds for the same file.

Can someone give an advice how to **move** (not copy) a file between two different drives?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
Create Temp folder in DriveX
Move fileX to temp folder
Copy temp folder to DriveY
Move file from Temp Folder on DriveY to Destination Folder
Delete Temp folders
```

This would be a lot of requests but MS Graph supports [batch requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching).

Comment: thanks for your answer! I will try it. I am only not sure if I will lose the original driveItemid if I would copy the folder containing the driveItem.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work as expected, moving a folder from one drive to another is not working at all as far as I have tried.